# Does saving an image on firebase under same reference delete the old one?

Tags: ios, database, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to better understand firebase storage, and I have two questions.

1. Does saving an image under the same reference delete the previously stored image in the storage, or does it keep it. Example : A user posts an image to `firebase`, I use the function `storage.putData`, to upload an image1 to the storage on firebase with the reference of `Storage.storage().reference().child("photo")`, and then I upload an image of the same ref to the storage, but a different image. Does this also delete the image1 from storage? Or does it keep it there, but is not accessible. I want to better keep my storage small.
2. Does  `storage.delete` delete all data of the deleted image from firebase? I wonder this because I pay for the blaze plan with `60 gbs` of storage, and I wanted to know if deleting and image with that function, lowers my storage and clears up actual space, or does it still keep some of it? I don't want be paying 100 $ a month, so I am really trying to delete any unimportant images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `StorageReference` is a reference to a specific, unique location on disk. Writing another image to the same reference overwrites the existing data at that location.

Calling `StorageReference.delete()` deletes the data at that location. After this you will no longer be charged for storing of the data.

Comment: ok so one last thing, you said it overwrites the existing data at that location, so would that mean example image1 would be deleted? and image2 would be replaced? Like is image1 data still in my storage somewhere? Sorry if this is a bad question.

Comment: You won't be charged anymore for the image data that you've overwritten, and it won't be available through the API or console. I can't comment on how it actually works though, I simply don't know.